# XPath to find last 3 items in a previous range

Tags: xml, xpath

Say I have the following XML snipit:

```
<ul>
  <li>alice</li>
  <li>bob</li>
  <li>carla</li>
  <li>dave</li>
  <li>eric</li>
  <li>fanny</li>
</ul>
<team>Team 1</team>
```

I want the last 3 members (dave, eric, fanny).

I can grab all team members with `//team/preceding::li`.

I am unsuccessful grabbing the last 3 members with range

`//team/preceding::li[last()-3 to last()]` or position 
 `//team/preceding::li[position() > last()-3]`

Comment: I took the liberty of correcting your XPath (`preceding` was `proceeding` in three places).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you are in the context of resolving `preceding::`, the order is the other way round – and returns to document order afterwards.

```
xml sel -t -c '//team/preceding::li[position() <= 3]' foo.xml 
<li>dave</li><li>eric</li><li>fanny</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

For XML

```
<ul>
  <li>alice</li>
  <li>bob</li>
  <li>carla</li>
  <li>dave</li>
  <li>eric</li>
  <li>fanny</li>
</ul>
```

use

```
//li[position() > last() - 3]
```

it selects exactly 3 last nodes.

Comment: @zhon, Can you provide real sample which reproduces your needs?

Comment: Thx @kirill, chris answered it nicely with //team/preceding::li[position() <= 3]